# Cypress basic authentication in all cy.visit requests

Tags: cypress

I have a `cy.visit()` calls with basic authentication which looks like this:

```
it('launch website', () => {
  cy.visit('url', {
  auth: {
    username: '....',
    password: '....',
  },
 })
```

And it works fine. But in order to make this code more useable, I dont want to hard code my credentials in every test, but I want to create a command so every time I visit that page, it uses my basic auth. I tried to implement solutions from [Adding basic auth to all requests in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67532277/adding-basic-auth-to-all-requests-in-cypress) , but it didnt work for me. It doesnt accept credentials that are stored in command. file. Any ideas other then those already mentioned?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Cypress custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Syntax) for this.

1. Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and wrte:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('authenticateUrl', (url, user, pass) => {
  cy.visit(url, {
    auth: {
      username: user,
      password: pass,
    },
  })
})
```

2. In your test you can just write this. You can pass url, username and passwords as parameters.

```js
cy.authenticateUrl('https://example.com', 'admin', 'pass123')
```

In case you don't want to use paramters, you can directly harcode url, username and password inside the custom command.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('authenticateUrl', () => {
  cy.visit('https://example.com', {
    auth: {
      username:'admin',
      password:'pass123',
    },
  })
})
```

In your test just use:

```js
it('launch website', () => {
  cy.authenticateUrl() //Launch URL and authenticate
})
```

Comment: But if I understand it correctly, with your solution im still filling username and password, right? I dont want that. I just want to have cy.visit() and it will use my basic authentication

Comment: Sorry, maybe im dumb, or im not able to think anymore today, but how exactly to use this function in my code so that cypress works without errors? 

```
it('launch website', () => {
  cy.visit('url', {

 })
```
If this is the code without the username and password, Do i still use cy.visit and the url in brackets? Or just replace cy.visit with cy.authenticateUrl? Because like that it doesnt work.
Sorry for being dumb, feel free to explain it to me like explaining to a monkey :(

Comment: After writing the custom commands you just have to use `cy.authenticateUrl()` in your test. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me error as well. I tried to run the code you you wrote and it says "cy.authenticateUrl is not a function"

Comment: Have you added the custom function in `cypress/support/commands.js` as mentioned in the ans.

Comment: Yep, its all included with correct parameters.

Comment: Then please add the content of your `cypress/support/commands.js` and your test file, to debug. Because this should work.

Answer (score 2):

This can be avoided by [overwriting](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands) the visit function. Add this to `cypress/support/index.js`

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalVisit, url) => {
    originalVisit(url, {
        auth: {
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password'
        }
    })
});
```

Notice that this code only working with `cy.visit(url)`. If you pass another arguments you should change it according to your situation.