# Cypress doesnt open application login popup and instead throws 401 unauthorized directly

Tags: authentication, cypress, ntlm

Its a simple code:
cy.visit("https://example.com/Booking/lists");

Hitting on this by browser internally redirects to "integrated authentication" which throws windows based login popup.
This works fine when done manually from any browser like chrome/edge
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViPfx.jpg)

However, when its done using cypress script then instead of the login pop up the browser immediately displays 401 - Unauthorized
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWV1D.jpg)

One suspection which I observe is that when browser is launched by cypress then remote address is send as 127.0.0.1:49898 for the internal API hit
However when I launch the browser manually then remote address is 10.20.120.40:443.

Is there anyway I can make cypress launch the browser with similar kind of setting/env as if launched manually ?

I expect login popup to be shown so that I can enter credentials using AutoIT script

Comment: Can you pass the username&password in the url itself, like `cy.visit('https://username:password@example.com/Booking/lists')` ?

Comment: That doesnt work my password has a special char - # in it

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Add-basic-auth-headers ?
or if you have auth on all pages, you may use the suggestion athttps://stackoverflow.com/a/72266068/1472458